# When is the suffix là to be used?

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm not sure when to use -là.
Is it ever obligatory?
If not, does it change the meaning of the phrase?

Take, for example,

> cet homme-là versus cet homme

Or

> Elle avait fermé son magasin plus tôt ce lundi-là

versus

> Elle avait fermé son magasin plus tôt ce lundi

Are any phrases wrong?

Comment: Why asking the very same question twice in a ten month interval?

Comment: I came around to the same exercise, and had de same doubt. Sorry